# Notification not vibrating or showing the light

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.6.0 Preview 2.1 and I'm trying to get vibrate and the light to work on the Galaxy S10 (Android 10) I'm testing my app on.  I get the notification, but the phone doesn't vibrate and the light doesn't come on.  I'd also like to have a sound as well, but nothing I've tried on here complies in Visual Studio as all examples/samples I can find are in java.  My code complies and runs without error.

```
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.OML.Android";
            string channelName = "Notifications Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, Android.App.NotificationImportance.None);
            chan.EnableLights(true);
            chan.EnableVibration(true);
            chan.LightColor = Color.Red;
            //chan.SetSound() <<-- simply can't figure out how to construct a Uri to the default sound
            chan.LockscreenVisibility = Android.App.NotificationVisibility.Private;
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.SetOngoing(true)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_box)
                    .SetContentTitle("Alert System")
                    .SetPriority(1)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .Build();
            StartForeground(2, notification);
        } else
        {
            Notification notify = new Notification();
            notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.All;
            StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notify);
        }
```

So what am I missing?

*** UPDATE ***

Per @Cherry Bu - MSFT's answer I changed my code to:

```
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.OML.Android";
            string channelName = "Notifications Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, Android.App.NotificationImportance.None);
            chan.EnableLights(true);
            chan.EnableVibration(true);
            chan.LightColor = Color.Red;
            chan.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification), new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build());
            chan.LockscreenVisibility = Android.App.NotificationVisibility.Private;
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.SetOngoing(true)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_box)
                    .SetContentTitle("Alert System")
                    .SetPriority(1)
                    //.SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
                    //,SetLights(Color.AliceBlue, 3000, 3000)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .Build();
            StartForeground(2, notification);
        } else
        {
            Notification notify = new Notification();
            notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.All;
            StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notify);
        }
        SingletonServicemanager.isMyServiceRunning = true;
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

I also added the following permissions to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

*** Update ***

Took a look at the github project @Cherry Bu - MSFT posted and I believe I'm doing exactly the same as he is but my code doesn't work, so in the interest of solving this I am posting the code for my foreground service.  First, the code I use to start the service which is part of my `Utils` code:

```
    public static void StartForegroundServiceComapt<SignalRSrv>(Context context, Bundle args = null) where SignalRSrv : Service
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(SignalRSrv));

        if (args != null)
        {
            intent.PutExtra("TheBundle", args);
        }

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            context.StartForegroundService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            context.StartService(intent);
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the code above, I'm starting a SignalR service, that code is:

```
public class SignalRSrv : Service
{
    private bool InstanceFieldsInitialized = false;
    private string username = "";
    private string firstname = "";
    private string lastname = "";
    private string company = "";
    private string department = "";
    private string section = "";
    private int notifyid = 0;
    public SignalRSingleton mInstance;

    private void InitializeInstanceFields()
    {
        mBinder = new LocalBinder(this);
    }

    private Handler mHandler; // to display any received messages
    private IBinder mBinder; // Binder given to clients
    private Notification notification = null;

    public SignalRSrv()
    {
        if (!InstanceFieldsInitialized)
        {
            InitializeInstanceFields();
            InstanceFieldsInitialized = true;
        }

    }

    public SignalRSingleton GetInstance()
    {
        return mInstance;
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        mInstance = SignalRSingleton.getInstance();
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
       try
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {
                StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
            }
            else
            {
                StopForeground(true);
            }

            StopSelf();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            var m = e.Message;
        }
    }


    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private void startSignalR(Bundle bundle)
    {

        User MyUser = bundle.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;
        if (MyUser.Department == null || MyUser.Department == "")
        {
            MyUser.Department = "none";
        }
        if (MyUser.Section == null || MyUser.Section == "")
        {
            MyUser.Section = "none";
        }
        mInstance.setmHubConnection(MyUser.Username, MyUser.Firstname ,MyUser.Lastname,MyUser.Company ,MyUser.Department,MyUser.Section, "FOREGROUND");
        mInstance.setHubProxy();

        try
        {
            // Connect the client to the hup
            mInstance.mHubConnection.Start().Wait(-1);

            mInstance.mHubProxy.On("broadcastMessage", (string platform, string message) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!isApplicationInTheBackground())
                    {
                        showMessage(message);
                    } else
                    {
                        showNotification(message, bundle, notification);
                    }

                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                   var error = e.Message;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (System.Exception e) when (e is InterruptedException || e is ExecutionException)
        {
            //opps

            //var x = 1;
            return;
        }
    }

    public async void showMessage(string message)
    {


        try
        {

            var result = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync(new ConfirmConfig
            {
                Message = "Alert - " + message,
                OkText = "Ok",

            });
            if (result)
            {
                // do something
                var x = message;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            var s = e.Message;
        }
    }
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {

        User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Bundle bundlee = intent.GetBundleExtra("TheBundle");
        MyUser = bundlee.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;

        username = MyUser.Username;
        firstname = MyUser.Firstname;
        lastname = MyUser.Lastname;
        company = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedCompany");
        department = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedDepartment");
        section = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedSection");

        startSignalR(bundlee);

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.OML.Android";
            string channelName = "Notifications Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, Android.App.NotificationImportance.None);
            chan.EnableLights(true);
            chan.EnableVibration(true);
            chan.LightColor = Color.Red;
            chan.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification), new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build());
            chan.LockscreenVisibility = Android.App.NotificationVisibility.Private;
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.SetOngoing(true)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_box)
                    .SetContentTitle("Alert System")
                    .SetPriority(1)
                    //.SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
                    //,SetLights(Color.AliceBlue, 3000, 3000)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .Build();
            StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        } else
        {
            Notification notify = new Notification();
            notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.All;
            StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notify);
        }
        SingletonServicemanager.isMyServiceRunning = true;
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    private void cancelnotification()
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Cancel(notifyid);

    }

    public void showNotification( string message, Bundle bundle, Notification notification)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
            MyUser = bundle.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;
            if (MyUser.Usertype != "")
            {
                if (MyUser.Usertype == "COMPADMIN")
                {
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Drawer)); //Activity you want to open
                } else if (MyUser.Usertype == "DEPTADMIN") {
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Drawer)); //Activity you want to open
                } else
                {
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(regUser)); //Activity you want to open
                }
            }
            else
            {
                intent = new Intent(this, typeof(regUser)); //Activity you want to open
            }
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            intent.PutExtra("TheBundle", bundle);
            intent.PutExtra("MessageReceived", message);

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, RandomGenerator(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"com.OML.Android")
                 .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_box)
                 .SetContentTitle("Message Received")
                 .SetContentText(message)
                 .SetAutoCancel(true)
                 .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notifyid = RandomGenerator();
            notificationManager.Notify(notifyid, notificationBuilder.Build());

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Utils.LogError("An error occured in SignalRSrv.cs ShowNotification, the error is: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    private int RandomGenerator()
    {
        return new Random().Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
    }
    private bool isApplicationInTheBackground()
    {
        bool isInBackground;

        RunningAppProcessInfo myProcess = new RunningAppProcessInfo();
        ActivityManager.GetMyMemoryState(myProcess);
        isInBackground = myProcess.Importance != Android.App.Importance.Foreground;

        return isInBackground;
    }
}

public class LocalBinder : Binder
{
    private readonly SignalRSrv outerInstance;

    public LocalBinder(SignalRSrv outerInstance)
    {
        this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
    }

    public virtual SignalRSrv Service
    {
        get
        {
            // Return this instance of SignalRSrv so clients can call public methods
            return outerInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

It is within the SignalRSrv code where I create the channel, is that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved it with assistance from @Cherry Bu - MSFT.  I integrated the `Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder` implemented in his solution into my project.  My show notification code now looks like this:

```
    public void showNotification( string message, Bundle bundle, Notification notification)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
            MyUser = bundle.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;

            var stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);

            if (MyUser.Usertype != "")
            {
                intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Drawer)); //Activity you want to open
                stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Class.FromType(typeof(Drawer)));
            }
            else
            {
                intent = new Intent(this, typeof(regUser)); //Activity you want to open
                stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Class.FromType(typeof(regUser)));
            }

            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            intent.PutExtra("TheBundle", bundle);
            intent.PutExtra("MessageReceived", message);

            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(intent);

            // Create the PendingIntent with the back stack:            
            var pendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                 .SetAutoCancel(true)
                 .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                 .SetContentTitle("OML Alert Received")
                 .SetContentText("Tap Here To View")
                 .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_box);


            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Utils.LogError("An error occured in SignalRSrv.cs ShowNotification, the error is: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'm not real clear why, or how, `Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder` has any impact on the creation of notification sound or vibration (the lights STILL do not work), but it obviously does.  I have two phones I test on, one with Android 8 and the other with Android 10.  The Android 8 phone has lights, but they are never activated. The android 10 phone apparently doesn't have lights as none of the other apps that turn lights on on the Android 8 phone turn them on on the Android 10 phone.

If anyone can explain why `TaskStackBuilder` affects this to me, I would appreciate it.  In any event, I'll mark his answer as the answer as it was that code sample that led me too this solution so all the credit goes to him.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, you want to add sound, light and vibrate for notifications, two permissions will allow.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Please add these two permissions in Mainfeast.

Then setting sound, light and vibrate like the code below.

```
 var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
        var description = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.Default)
                      {
                          Description = description
                      };
        channel.EnableVibration(true);
        channel.EnableLights(true);
        channel.LightColor = Color.Red;
        channel.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification),new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build());
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
```

**Note**:when you test the vibrate function,remember to lock the screen of your device firstly, then you will look light when app get notification.

If you want to set custom sound, I find one thread about this, you can take a look:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/148652/how-to-make-a-wav-file-the-default-push-notification-sound-for-the-app

**Note:** Please don't forget to add permissions to read and write sound file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Made the suggested changes to my code, no change, got the notification but no lights, vibration or sound.

Comment: @PrescottChartier I have provide one sample at github, please download this sample to test at your device:https://github.com/CherryBu/notificationsample I test at Google Piex(Android 8.1),because I don't have Galaxy S10 (Android 10), it works fine. Please note if you want to see light, please run this project firstly, then lock the screen of your device , I set one Timer to send notification every 8 second, finally you will look light when app get notification.

Comment: The github project does create the sound and vibration, no light though.  I'm thinking the phone doesn't have a light.  In any event, I get the sound and vibration, but for some reason I do not with my app.  Something is clearly wrong with my app if that's the case.

Comment: I added ALL the code that deals with the foreground service where I receive notifications.

Comment: @PrescottChartier So if you any solution about your problem, please post your reply here and mark it, or please mark the helpful post as answer, thanks.